# Unreal Engine 4.20 crashes when I try to play?

Tags: c++, version-control, crash, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I'm making a Simple escape the room game using unreal 4.20 and C++ on my Windows 10 Machine. The code builds/complies just fine but when I hit play the Engines crashes. I've tried restarting my computer, deleting all files files/directories except for config, content, source folders, and the .uproject file. I tried deleting the engine, but it won't let me due to administrator permissions. I'm currently on the "Open door" class

Here is my OpenDoor.h file:

```
 #pragma once

 #include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "Engine/TriggerVolume.h"
#include "OpenDoor.generated.h"


 UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
 class BUILDINGESCAPE_API UOpenDoor : public UActorComponent
 {
    GENERATED_BODY()

  public:   
  // Sets default values for this component's properties
   UOpenDoor();

 protected:
  // Called when the game starts
  virtual void BeginPlay() override;
 private:
  void OpenDoor();

  // Called every frame
  virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, 
   FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;
 public:
   UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
     float OpenAngle = 90.0f; 
   UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
     ATriggerVolume* PressurePlate;

   UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
     AActor* ActorThatOpens; // Remember pawn inherits from actor


   };
```

Here is my OpenDoor.cpp file:

```
 // Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "OpenDoor.h"


// Sets default values for this component's properties
UOpenDoor::UOpenDoor()
{
// Set this component to be initialized when the game starts, and to be 
 ticked every frame.  You can turn these features
   // off to improve performance if you don't need them.
  PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;

  // ...
 }


// Called when the game starts
void UOpenDoor::BeginPlay()
{
 Super::BeginPlay();


 // ...

}
void UOpenDoor::OpenDoor()
{
  // Find the owning Actor
  AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
 }

// Called every frame
void UOpenDoor::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, 
FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
  Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

   // Poll the Trigger Volume
   // If the ActorThatOpens is in the volume
   if (PressurePlate->IsOverlappingActor(ActorThatOpens))
    {
     OpenDoor();
    }
}
```

I'm new to Unreal and struggle with C++ as a language in General, so I wonder if its an issue with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: On which line does it crash? Have you tried debugging it? You know, one does not go and randomly delete things if something crashes, he needs to investigate the reason causing the crash. It may be a good idea to spend some time learning C++ prior to jumping into large and complex frameworks, such as UE.

Comment: `PressurePlate` is not checked for nullness before being dereferenced in `TickComponent`.

Comment: Go into your saved folder, then logs folder, and see what the last log said at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the null pointers of the

> PressurePlate

and the

> ActorThatOpens

It's also a good practice to secure all pointers before using them so you don't get a crash for deferencing null pointers. Even so, your code should work, probably you are forgetting to set the reference on the editor.

I fixed that for you:

```
void UOpenDoor::OpenDoor()
{
  // Find the owning Actor
  if(!GetOwner()) return;
  AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
 }

// Called every frame
void UOpenDoor::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, 
FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
  Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

   // Poll the Trigger Volume
   // If the ActorThatOpens is in the volume
   if (PressurePlate == nullptr) //Checking for the PressurePlate
   {
      UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Missing PressurePlate");
      return;
   }
   if(ActorThatOpens == nullptr) // Checking for the Door
   {
   UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Missing ActorThatOpens");
   return;
   }
   if (PressurePlate->IsOverlappingActor(ActorThatOpens))
    {
     OpenDoor();
    }
}
```